# Help understanding the limit comparison test?

Tags: real-analysis

I have always been under the impression that the limit comparison test was as follows:

Suppose that we have two series  $\sum a_n$  and $\sum b_n$ with  $a_n$, $b_n$ ≥ 0  for all  n.

Then if $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}$ = c with 0 < c < $\infty$ then either both series converge or both series diverge.

However, my real analysis textbook states this:

Suppose that X = ($x_n$) and Y = ($y_n$) are nonzero real sequences and suppose that the following limit exists in R:

r = $\lim_{n\to\infty}{|\frac{x_n}{y_n}|}$

a) If r ≠ 0, then $\sum{x_n}$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $\sum{y_n}$ is absolutely convergent.

b) If r = 0 and if $\sum{y_n}$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum{x_n}$ is absolutely convergent.

I really don't understand the difference between statements a and b and I don't see how this is the limit comparison test I know and love.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first statement, if $r\neq 0$, states exactly what you said: either both series converge or they both diverge. This makes sense as the limit states that both series go towards their limit aprocimately with the same speed (up to a constant)

The second expands what you already know by telling you what happens if $r=0$. In that case, the elements $y_n$ fall towards $0$ "more slowly" than the elements $x_n$, so if they fall fast enough to ensure convergence, surely the elements $x_n$ must as well.

Comment: And the second?  I guess I'm having trouble grasping the difference between "if" and "if and only if" in these two cases.

Comment: "$A$ if and only if $B$" means either both $A$ and $B$ are true or neither is. "$A$ if $B$" means that if $B$ is true, then $A$ must be true. The statement tells you nothing if $B$ is not true.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample for $r=0$ take $x_n=\frac 1 {n^2}$ and $y_n=\frac 1 n$  and the first series is convergent and the second is divergent.